Rook Ceph storage and MySQL space very big difference
Can someone please advise me what could be the cause of this condition?
I have a Rook Ceph cluster on which MySQL database with 3x replication is stored. This database is used by me for development too, i.e. a lot of data is deleted, changed and so on.
BinaryLogs are also enabled.
In total the database takes 27GB, 22-24 of which are BinaryLogs. I can disable BinaryLogs but 20 gigabytes does not play a huge role, they are cleared every 3 days.
I see the same size(27GB) if I look at the size from container/host (df -h).
But Rook Ceph defines this Block Image as 241GB.
And I can't understand why this size of Block Image so big if it should be 9 times smaller?
Ideas, hints? What can I try or in what direction to look to understand what the reason is.

The major difference in the storage between the Ceph and MySQL is due to their designs and the data handling capabilities. However the main difference is MySQL stores the data in the tables with schemas and Ceph is mainly for storing unstructured data like media, backups and other objects. You can also achieve this with the help of the Devopscube Article by Bibin Wilson & Shishir Khandelwal on How to Reduce Docker Image Size: 6 Optimization Methods for more details.

@Imran Premnawaz - Thanks for the answer, but I think you do not understood the question itself. Docker image size for my question is another field and hat nothing with my question.

Imran's comment here looks like a straight copy and paste from a chatbot.

I'm not familiar with Ceph but I think there's confusion here about what you are measuring. You've described the size from 3 different perspectives but not given the explicit method (command line) you used to get the size.
While Ceph can store individual files, running a MySQL database via this interface would be rather odd - I'm guessing that the storage is provisioned a Ceph block device. In this scenario there is a fixed upper limit on the size defined at the time of provisioning and configured in the filesystem you create on the volume. Most (all?) storage providers will implement thin provisioning - the footprint of the volume on the storage is only the blocks which have been written to in the volumes lifecycle. Ceph does this by default. i.e. as long as you only ever add data, then the footprint will reflect the size of files stored in the filesystem.
However the storage provider doesn't understand about filesystems - it doesn't know when a file is removed from the filesystem, so the blocks of underlying storage remain allocated when the file is deleted. The host using the storage has to tell Ceph when the blocks are no longer in use - it only does that if the filesystem is mounted with the discard option or when an explicit fstrim command is run.
A further consideration is that your storage should be setup with redundancy - i.e. the ability to continue to provide the service when a node fails. Its not unusual for a ceph cluster to have 3 (sometimes even more) copies of every data block. Your method may be reporting the space used across physical storage rather than the logical footprint.

Thank you so much for your answer.
I think you gave me exactly what I was looking for.
Yes, we are talking about CephBlockStorage.
I assumed that in my case Ceph adds incrementally but does not delete. I just couldn't explain such size differences any other way.
I just didn't know how and what to look for.
Regarding the 3 copies, this I indicated correctly. Since 3 copies take up 720GB respectively and this is shown in the cluster.
So, 2 keywords that pointed the way: "discard" and "fstrim"
About discard is also described in the StorageClass documentation
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#storageclass-objects
https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/rbd/rbd-kubernetes/#create-a-storageclass
But this solution is not optimal and there may be performance problems.
For this purpose Rook Ceph suggests using special addons that will do this work regularly.
Here is an identical issue: https://github.com/rook/rook/issues/10391
And here are the solutions: https://rook.io/docs/rook/v1.14/Storage-Configuration/Ceph-CSI/ceph-csi-drivers/#csi-addons-operations
I think the question is solved, because I already understand what I need to configure and so on. Whether it will work correctly or not is another question. But it should work.
